# What HTTP method should I use if my endpoint will perform database CREATE and UPDATE operations?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to backend development. I still wonder what the correct route method is if the controller has different types of database actions. the example below is not the "exact" code but it does explain of what I'm trying to do.

```
const purchase = async (req, res) => {
  await updateThisOneFromDatabase();
  await createThisOneFromDatabase();

   return res.status(200).json({});
}
```

Comment: what are the choices? and why do you update and then create? seems an odd way to do things

Comment: You use the method suitable for the overall action the endpoint does

Comment: I see. I was thinking I can perform multiple actions in just one method

Comment: if that's what you want, then do it - we don't know what's right, it's your code. My point was that update followed by create seems odd ... what are you updating if you haven't created yet?

Comment: a specific document from my database. It does work with the POST method btw, but it seems like I'm not doing it right since the POST should be doing CREATE and so with PUT

Answer (score 1):

for create or insert to database, POST method is most recomended

The HTTP POST method sends data to the server. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header.

The difference between PUT and POST is that PUT is idempotent: calling it once or several times successively has the same effect (that is no side effect), where successive identical POST may have additional effects, like passing an order several times.

A POST request is typically sent via an HTML form and results in a change on the server. In this case, the content type is selected by putting the adequate string in the enctype attribute of the  element or the formenctype attribute of the  or  elements:

When the POST request is sent via a method other than an HTML form — like via an XMLHttpRequest — the body can take any type. As described in the HTTP 1.1 specification, POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:

Annotation of existing resources
Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or similar group of articles;
Adding a new user through a signup modal;
Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process;

Kindly refer below for more information

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp